# How to add single @XmlAttribute annotations to class which can be applicable to all objects within that class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, moxy

I have a class that has many fields all of the fields will be `Attribute` of the `XML` element during the `JAXB Marshalling`. As of now, I have annotated each of the fields with `@XmlAttribute`, and it's working fine.

Now I am refactoring the code so I was wondering if there is a way to add a single `@XmlAttribute` so that it can be applicable to all the fields in that class so that I do not have to add `@XmlAttribute` to each field.

Something similar to `@Getter` and `@Setter` from `Project Lombok`. It can be added either on each field or it can be added on the class so applicable to all private fields within that class.

I tried adding on the class and it throws me exceptions `XmlNamedAttribute cannot be resolved to a type`.

I have nearly 15-20 fields all of which will be an attribute so wondering for a shortcut method rather than adding annotation on each field.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Reports {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;
    
    //Similarly I have 15-20 fields
}
```

Looking for the shortcut something like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlAttribute
public class Reports {
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String name;
    //Similarly I have 15-20 fields
}
```

As of now, everything is working fine. Just wanted to confirm if there is a better approach.

If no direct approach is available then can we write a custom `JAXB XMLAdapter` for it? If so can someone provide a basic skeleton or suggestions on the same?

Nothing seems to be working for me. I tried even `Moxy` which uses the implementation.

Comment: I tried a lot of things still nothing seems to be an alternative to this problem. Still looking for an answer if anyone is willing to provide the same.